# Why isn't the line-height property of <input> what I set in CSS?

Tags: input, css

I explicitly set the `line-height` property of an `<input>` element in CSS. But when I check the element in firebug, the `line-height` value of this element is not what I set in CSS. And it seems that the line-height value has nothing to do with what I set in CSS. What is the possible reason for this?

Comment: lol. Asking for a downvote here. No description whatsoever. You're basically saying "I have a problem with CSS, why?"

Comment: Can we see your relevant code? It is hard to debug without knowing what is actually going on. @JacksonGariety downvote worthy, but don't be condescending.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Mind Reader or Crystal Ball.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128551/133242)

Comment: To help the OP, I made a jsfiddle showing the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/Uq5Tt/1/ If you query the input element with Firefox, you'll see that the line-height is not what I specified. And `!important` doesn't help. Ideas anyone? [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#sTypoAscender) says that line-height applies to: all elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [definition of `line-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) in the CSS 2.1 specification, it has a specific meaning for block container elements and a different meaning for non-replaced inline elements. I can’t find any statement on replaced inline elements there, and an `input` element can be regarded as a replaced element, somewhat debatably.

Anyway, odd as it may seem, browsers seem to ignore `line-height` on `input` elements. As a workaround, you might consider setting the `height` property, or setting vertical padding. But the results won’t be consistent across browsers. As a rule of thumb, we should expect the rendering of a text input box to the under the control of the browser, though in some cases some features can be tuned using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if that was the point but i specified margin, padding and got rid of border, here you got exactly 14px: http://jsfiddle.net/mymlyn/Uq5Tt/2/

if you check the dev tools it is (and was before specyfying the above) exactly 14px:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26827941/ScreenShot060.png (chrome dev tools)
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26827941/ScreenShot061.png (firebug in ff)

the reason in your case might be that your input field has a specified id or class,

```
<input id="someID"/>
```

and there is something like

```
input#someID {line-height: 20px;}
```

in your css somewhere else, andyou might be trying to change its value by setting

```
input {line-height: 14px;}
```

if that was not the case im out of ideas :)

Answer (score -1):

The lineheight wont be rendered in firefox but i think it will be in IE. There's a small trick to do, which is to let lineheight style to be rendered as block elements instead of an inline elements.

For example:

This will not work

```
span {font-size:12px; line-height:14px}
```

But this will:

```
span {font-size:12px; line-height:14px; display:block;}
```

Comment: This answer has missinformation and isn't actually that helpfull. There is no particular difference in how line-height is treated in IE or Firefox unless we're talking about IE6/7, but I can only assume that is far from relevant. "'wrapping' your line-height in a block area" is not the right phrasing and I doubt you have a clear understanding of the [difference between inline and block level elements](http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/). For real information on how lin-height works see http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/line-height